How do I do localization and translation with AssetStudioGUI?
I need to find someone who knows how to work with AssetStudioGUI because I'm trying to make a Czech localization for Kindergarten 1, 2 and in the future 3, but there really aren't any tutorials for that (only to change a picture and such). And I know it must be possible to do so, because I saw a Russian and Spanish localization.
The only thing I managed to figure out over the weeks was to find the font it uses, and to make that font to support Czech letters, AND to locate some text files (outside AssetStudio) and translated some of the dialogue. And yes, as you can see the "Garten" part of "Kindergarten" is lost somewhere?
So... now what?
How do I replace the old font with the new one? And can I change the text in the ASGUI itself? Or do I have to find a specific Unity text file with all dialogues and such?



Does the original game features already some localization or is it a single language game? It might be as easy that they load all strings from a property file or they hard coded each text on the buttons/ dialog options

@Zibelas
The devs did want to make Portuguese translation but that was years ago, and never really made real :c
Its mentioned on steam community forum here: https://steamcommunity.com/app/589590/discussions/0/1290690669217603300/
And its a single language game to answer your first question :D
